# What is the point of window_magic in SDL?

Tags: sdl-2

While browsing the SDL source code that interfaces with the system window manager, I encountered [`struct SDL_VideoDevice`](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/ac1c949c14b4/src/video/SDL_sysvideo.h#l145) with a mystical `Uint8 window_magic` field. There doesn't seem to be any documentation for this field. What is the purpose of this field? It plays a role in the following functions/macros (all defined in [`SDL_video.c`](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/ac1c949c14b4/src/video/SDL_video.c)).

The macro [`CHECK_WINDOW_MAGIC`](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/ac1c949c14b4/src/video/SDL_video.c#l116):

```c
#define CHECK_WINDOW_MAGIC(window, retval) \
    if (!_this) { \
        SDL_UninitializedVideo(); \
        return retval; \
    } \
    if (!window || window->magic != &_this->window_magic) { \
        SDL_SetError("Invalid window"); \
        return retval; \
    }
```

The function [`SDL_GetWindowWMInfo`](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/ac1c949c14b4/src/video/SDL_video.c#l3504):

```c
SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(SDL_Window * window, struct SDL_SysWMinfo *info)
{
    CHECK_WINDOW_MAGIC(window, SDL_FALSE);

    if (!info) {
        SDL_InvalidParamError("info");
        return SDL_FALSE;
    }
    info->subsystem = SDL_SYSWM_UNKNOWN;

    if (!_this->GetWindowWMInfo) {
        SDL_Unsupported();
        return SDL_FALSE;
    }
    return (_this->GetWindowWMInfo(_this, window, info));
}
```

The function [`SDL_CreateWindow`](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/ac1c949c14b4/src/video/SDL_video.c#l1331):

```c
SDL_Window *
SDL_CreateWindow(const char *title, int x, int y, int w, int h, Uint32 flags)
{
    ...
    window->magic = &_this->window_magic;
    ...
}
```

`_this` is a pointer to an `SDL_VideoDevice`, which is initialized when the user calls `SDL_Init`. When the user calls `SDL_CreateWindow`, SDL assignes `window->magic` to the address of `_this->window_magic`. As far as I can tell, `_this->window_magic` is never initialized anywhere in SDL. What could possibly be the role of this value?

Comment: not sure if related, but from what i understand magic and more magic is used to describe code that can't be explained how or why it works https://www.google.com/search?q=magic+more+magic

Comment: whats the point of SDL in general ?

Answer (score 0):

It uses address of `_this->window_magic`, not its value. Variable don't have to be initialised to have an address, especially if it is a structure field.

Its purpose is to quickly check against uninitialised window, or not a window at all. No guarantees but hit rate is very high - it is very unlikely that anything will accidentially match the address of SDL's internal structure.